# How to click on the first matching element having a specific background-url using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<div class="__section-image" style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/all/05_element/continentImg/1.png&quot;);"></div>
```

The website have a lot of this html. I want to click the first of them.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the first matching element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='__section-image']")[0].click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='__section-image']")[0].click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the first matching element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='__section-image']")))[0].click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='__section-image']")))[0].click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```